# Trying to analyze a cohort dataset with many households in SAS, how to code to look within a household?

Tags: if-statement, sas, dataset

I'm still pretty new to SAS and trying to wrangle a dataset. In the dataset, households were recruited if one of them had a confirmed positive respiratory illness. Each member has their own participant ID and a household ID and if people within the same household have the same household ID.

I'm trying to define the index case by saying, if they are in the same household, then see which participant has the same onset date, and then create a new variable calling that person the index.

I was thinking something like this, but need help making it functional.

```
data house; 
set house;
if householdID==householdID and min(onsetdate) then index=1; 
else if index = 0; 
run;
```

Thanks!!

To clarify ideally it would be something like this:

| PTID | HouseholdID | OnsetDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 10/11/2022 |
| 11 | 1 | 10/14/2022 |
| 12 | 1 | 10/9/2022 |
| 13 | 2 | 10/11/2022 |
| 14 | 2 | 10/12/2022 |

Then, I would like SAS to create a new variable by looking at those with the same HouseholdID annd seeing who had the first date of symptoms. That person would be the index case '1' and otherwise would be '0'.

| PTID | HouseholdID | OnsetDate | IndexCase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 10/11/2022 | 0 |
| 11 | 1 | 10/14/2022 | 0 |
| 12 | 1 | 10/9/2022 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 | 10/11/2022 | 1 |
| 14 | 2 | 10/12/2022 | 0 |

Comment: You cannot have two equal operators next to each other.  But comparing a value to itself will always be true, so what two values are you actually trying to compare?  To clarify what you are asking for show a simple example input dataset and what output you expect.

Comment: Just added input and output tables to hopefully clarify! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this: (aside, overwriting a dataset with one of the same name is not often the best idea)

```
proc sort data=house; by householdID onsetdate; run;

data want;
   set house;
   by householdID onsetdate;
   retain refdate;
   /* Take the first onset date as reference - assumes no missing values! */
   if first.householdID then refdate = onsetdate;
   index = onsetdate eq refdate;
run;
```